# Sqlite3 Python: How to do an efficient bulk update?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, bulkupdate

I can do very efficient bulk inserts in Sqlite3 on Python (2.7) with this code:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", data)
```

But I can't get updates to work efficiently. I thought it might be a problem of the database structure/indexing, but even on a test database with only one table of 100 rows, the update still takes about 2-3 seconds.

I've tried different code variations. The latest code I have is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794260/6227834) to a previous question about update and executemany, but it's just as slow for me as any other attempt I've made:

```
data = []
for s in sources:
    source_id = s['source_id']
    val = get_value(s['source_attr'])
    x=[val, source_id]
    data.append(x)
cur.executemany("UPDATE sources SET source_attr = ? WHERE source_id = ?", data)
con.commit()
```

How could I improve this code to do a big bulk update efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

When inserting a record, the database just needs to write a row at the end of the table (unless you have something like UNIQUE constraints).

When updating a record, the database needs to find the row. This requires scanning through the entire table (for each command), unless you have an index on the search column:

```sql
CREATE INDEX whatever ON sources(source_id);
```

But if `source_id` is the [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key), you should just declare it as such (which creates an implicit index):

```sql
CREATE TABLE sources(
    source_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    source_attr TEXT,
    [...]
);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's already indexed. Hoping to improve from there :)